# Using radio values to forward to specific web pages on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have some very simple forms that will send the user to a specific webpage based on their selected radio option. I figured these would append the value to some sort of variable that something like jquery could read and forward onto the webpage we specify.

```
 <form id="weight-loss">
        <input type="radio" id="form1_option1" name="weight-loss" value="5_day" class="plan" /><label for="form1_option1"> 5 Day - All Inclusive Price</label><br />
        <input type="radio" id="form1_option2" name="weight-loss" value="7_day" /><label for="form1_option2"> 7 Day - All Inclusive Price</label><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Place Order" alt="Submit button" class="orange_btn" />
</form>
```

I can't seem to find anything that really helps in this regard on the web. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. The obvious fix was to simply set a radio button as selected by default. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pRhjq/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function choosePage() {
        if(document.getElementById('weightloss').form1_option1.checked) {
            window.location.replace( "http://google.com/" );
        }
        if(document.getElementById('weightloss').form1_option2.checked) {
            window.location.replace( "http://yahoo.com/" );
        }
    }
</script>

<form id="weightloss">
     <input type="radio" id="form1_option1" name="weight-loss" value="5_day" class="plan">
     <label for="form1_option1"> 5 Day - All Inclusive Price</label><br>
     <input type="radio" id="form1_option2" name="weight-loss" value="7_day">
     <label for="form1_option2"> 7 Day - All Inclusive Price</label><br>
     <input type="button" value="Place Order" alt="Submit button" class="orange_btn" onclick="choosePage()">
</form>
```

Comment: +1 for adding a jsfiddle - my new favorite, give me an example of how to do something site

Answer (score 0):

Use this: http://www.techiegyan.com/2008/07/09/using-jquery-check-boxes-and-radio-buttons/

In combo with this: window.location.href = 'new_location.htm';

Answer (score -1):

At the simplest, you could make the form's method a GET:

```
<form id="weight-loss" method="get" action="some_page.php">
    <input type="radio" id="form1_option1" name="weight-loss" value="5_day" class="plan" /><label for="form1_option1"> 5 Day - All Inclusive Price</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="form1_option2" name="weight-loss" value="7_day" /><label for="form1_option2"> 7 Day - All Inclusive Price</label><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Place Order" alt="Submit button" class="orange_btn" />
</form>
```

Then you can have some_page.php display different pages based on the value of its weight-loss variable. Or, at the very least, it could redirect based on that variable.

Comment: why would you assume this is php?